# Cryptography encryption exception with RijndaelManaged in IOS platform(Using Xamarin Shared Project)

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm using below code for encrypting key, that is accepted in Xamarin.android platform but in Xamarin.IOS facing issues in encryption

/* values are passing to the Method*/

private static string EncryptionKey = "midev-acu!!";

private static byte[] aesIV = { 251, 188, 78, 246, 76, 129, 238, 77, 198, 74, 208, 88, 97, 151, 36, 107 };

StringtoEncrypt = 10049

```
 public static string AesEncrypt(string stringToEncrypt, string SEncryptionKey)

    {
        try
        {
            key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(SEncryptionKey.Substring(0, 8));
            RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt);
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            //cs.Close();// added 6/1/2015 NP
            string encryptedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            //ms.Close();// added 6/1/2015 NP
            return encryptedValue;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
```

Exception raised during the execution of **aes.CreateEncryptor(key, aesIV)** method

at Crimson.CommonCrypto.Cryptor.Create (Crimson.CommonCrypto.CCOperation operation, Crimson.CommonCrypto.CCAlgorithm algorithm, Crimson.CommonCrypto.CCOptions options, System.Byte[] key, System.Byte[] iv) [0x00057] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.cs:98 
  at System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged.CreateEncryptor (System.Byte[] rgbKey, System.Byte[] rgbIV) [0x00024] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.10.0.36/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/CommonCrypto/RijndaelManaged.cs:67 
  at FFA.Components.Encryption.AesEncrypt (System.String stringToEncrypt, System.String SEncryptionKey) [0x0003d] in E:\SVN\Acuative\FFA\FFA\Components\Encryption.cs:60

Please provide the better solution to resolve this exception Xamarin.IOS platform, that is really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I dont think you posted the actual exception message.

Comment: Yes,that is StackTrace, Exception message is "Error occurred during a cryptographic operation."

Comment: Always use full length keys. Otherwise you will get an error of some unspecified padding ranging from 0x00 to whatever garbage follows the supplied key. Yuri has the correct answer, accept it.

Comment: Looks like this user never accepts answers. ok...

Comment: not like that, it's really really helpful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your key. It has to be at least 16 bytes:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9df14hc(v=vs.110).aspx

```
        byte[] aesIV = { 251, 188, 78, 246, 76, 129, 238, 77, 198, 74, 208, 88, 97, 151, 36, 107 };
        string EncryptionKey = "midev-acu1214144234545235!!";
        try
        {
            var key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(EncryptionKey.Substring(0, 16));
            RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged();
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            byte[] inputByteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("10049");
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            var encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(key, aesIV);
            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
            //cs.Close();// added 6/1/2015 NP
            string encryptedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
            //ms.Close();// added 6/1/2015 NP
            //return encryptedValue;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
```